# R crashes when trying to add a plot on a powerpoint template

Tags: r, powerpoint, plotly, reporters

I have developed a dashboard using R and the library shiny, where some different charts are displayed. These ones aren't static charts but they are generated dynamically according to some filters you can set through some bottons and so on.

The next step, what I am working on right now it would be to create a powerpoint report including those charts I have generated before. I got this piece of code so far:

```
report <- pptx(template = 'report_template.pptx')
report <- addSlide(report,"report_layout") 
slide.layouts(report)
slide.layouts(report, "report_layout")
report <- addPlot(report, function() print(p))
writeDoc(report, "example_report.pptx")
```

Being p a given chart created by plotly this way:

```
p <- plot_ly(agregado_cedex(), labels = ~Escalado, values = ~Total,type = "pie",
          text = ~Total, width = 500, height = 250, hoverinfo = "none") %>% config(displayModeBar = FALSE) %>%
layout(title = "Desglose incidencias", showlegend = TRUE,
       xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
       yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
```

There is no problem with this chart as it is correctly displayed on the shiny app (dashboard).

When executing the code above I am getting the next error on R Studio:

```
Warning: Error in .jcall: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.]
```

I found something a similar post but it haven't been solved so far [Add plots in PPTx without crashing R using addplot()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36092569/add-plots-in-pptx-without-crashing-r-using-addplot)

Does anyone know what is wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ReporteRs` does not support htmlwidgets. `addPlot` work with base plot commands, ggplot2, grid and lattice.

Comment: Thanks @David Gohel. Does this mean `ReporteRs` cant work with `plotly` charts? However it should work with `ggplot2` ones, right? And another thing, am I using the correct sintax for the function `addPlot`?? Cause I have seen some documentation where it is used this way: `report <- addPlot(report, function(print), x=p )` or something like this

Comment: @LuisCano plotly charts are htmlwidgets, not graphical device (arg, it's complicated...). yes

Comment: Ok, I got it now... However, I also tried with some ggplot2 charts and I couldnt make it work. The code for that chart is something like this: `p7 <- ggplot2(some stuff inside this)`. This chart is inside a `render plot` function and it is correctly displayed in my shiny app. Then I tried to add it to the PPTX file: `report <- addPlot(report, function() print(p7))`. I got this error `Warning: Error in print: object 'p7' not found`. I am not an expert in R as you can see... Do you know what might be wrong @DavidGohel?